# Android RTSP streaming buffer size for delayed playback

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I can access and view RTSP streams from IP cameras on Android via the VideoView component without problems.

Now I need to play the RTSP stream with a delay (i.e. if I specify a 30 second delay, the playback on screen should be 30 seconds behind the source and the delay needs to be variable though not during playback, only at the point of connecting to the source).

I originally thought this would not be a problem as I could simply change the RTSP buffer duration before connecting to the camera but unfortunately it seems the buffer size is baked into the firmware and cannot be changed in software. Now I have got a horrible feeling that my way forward will be to compile a version of FFMpeg for Android and somehow get the stream data out from the library, buffer it and then render it myself and I have no experience with FFMpeg.

I am unsure how I would now go about solving this problem and any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Sorry I forgot to mention, the RTSP stream is being accessed over WiFi on a LAN so no huge latency issues here from going over the Internet.

Comment: Duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924834/decode-of-live-rtsp-stream-large-video-lag-using-mediaplayer-on-android